# Why is this a closure?

Tags: javascript, closures

I got this code snippets from this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming))

```
// Return a list of all books with at least 'threshold' copies sold.
function bestSellingBooks(threshold) {
  return bookList.filter(
      function (book) { return book.sales >= threshold; }
    );
}
```

And wiki page states this is an example of closure.

Where is a closure in this snippets?

As far as i know, closure consists of two critical attribute, a returned function and an environment in which that function was created.

Moreover, there shold be some variable that outlive the scope of the function that creates it.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work). You should be able to find your answer by reading through some of those answers at least.

Comment: As long as anonymous function has access to its outer function – it is closure. `threshold` variable is not passed to returned function but you have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ParkerSuperstar/ef53mzvL/)

I've simplified the code to try to make the concepts more clear.

```
var threshold = 50;
var retVal = getPastThreshold(threshold);
threshold = 1;
alert(retVal);

function useFunction(someFunction) {
    alert(someFunction);
    return someFunction(40);
}

// Returns true if number is past 'threshold'.
function getPastThreshold(threshold) {
  return useFunction( function (someNumber) { return someNumber >= threshold; });
}
```

You can see from the alert that the function being passed around, someFunction, contains the variable threshold but no value for it. We can see that the value for threshold is not being scoped from var threshold, which is modified so that, if it were in scope, the boolean return value in the next alert would not be false but true; however, the value for threshold is static from when the function getPastThreshold was initially invoked. This is due to closure.

Answer (score 0):

`threshold` is defined as parameter in function `bestSellingBooks` and is used in function `function (book) { return book.sales >= threshold; }` (which does not redefine it). By definition this is closure.